# Does not exist in the current context. Variable declaration

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

I'm looking for a person to explain this code to me and tell why I'm getting this error.

> C:\Users\04albjoh\Downloads\VS code\app\Program.cs(20,30): error CS0103: The name 'customers' does not exist in the current context [C:\Users\04albjoh\Downloads\VS code\app\app.csproj]

```
*// Example #1: var is optional when
// the select clause specifies a string
string[] words = { "apple", "strawberry", "grape", "peach", "banana" };
var wordQuery = from word in words
                where word[0] == 'g'
                select word;

// Because each element in the sequence is a string,
// not an anonymous type, var is optional here also.
foreach (string s in wordQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

// Example #2: var is required because
// the select clause specifies an anonymous type

var custQuery = from cust in customers
                where cust.City == "Phoenix"
                select new { cust.Name, cust.Phone };

// var must be used because each item
// in the sequence is an anonymous type
foreach (var item in custQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name={0}, Phone={1}", item.Name, item.Phone);
}*
```

**I tried adding**

```
this: customers = {}
```

**above**

```
var custQuery = from cust in customers
                where cust.City == "Phoenix"
                select new { cust.Name, cust.Phone };
```

Comment: where do you think `customers` is declared / what do you expect it to be?

Comment: Will recommend having a quick look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers?redirectedfrom=MSDN . Especially the differente codeblock with "Cat". It should cover class creation, constructor, initalisation of one object . Initialisation of a list of object

Answer (score 1):

You've copied this code from the [C# Language Reference: Declaration statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/declarations).

That code is meant to be read, not compiled.

The variable `customers` is any collection of types that at least have `City`, `Name` and `Phone` properties, but the point of that code block is that when you `select` into an anonymous type, you'll have to declare the variable to store those in as `var`.

Answer (score 0):

Define a class `Customer` which has properties City, Name and Phone with the relevant datatypes and initialize the `customers` as the List of object of class `Customer` like `List<Customer> customers`